# Intuition behind choosing partition in decision tree ID3 algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree, supervised-learning

I'm trying to understand intuition behind decision tree classifier in ML. I know that the goal at each node in the decision tree is to further partition current space of possible labels such that as many candidate labels are eliminated as possible based on answer to given question at that node. But how is that related to choosing a partition based on attribute that minimizes partition "entropy"? Where "entropy" is defined as follows:

```
H(S) = −p_1*log2(p_1) −... −p_n*log2(p_n)
```

and partition entropy:

```
H = q_1*H(S_1) +...+ q_m*H(S_m)

with H(S): entropy of a given subset
     H: partition entropy
     p_i's: proportions of data belonging to class i
     q_i's: proportions of data belonging to subset i based on given partition
```

Also, must the "question" at each node be a yes/no question and thus splits the current label space into 2? As opposed to 3 or more subsets? Any clear example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> . But how is that related to choosing a partition based on attribute that minimizes partition "entropy"?

Entropy (here, Shannon's entropy) is a measure of uncertainty, it simply expresses how clear is your per-class separation. If entropy is high - then there are lots of samples from different classes, thus splitting in this feature would be valuable, as there is clearly a need for more decision rules to separate the objects. On the other hand if entropy is small - the node already consists mostly of samples from one class thus there is no point in further splitting. In particular you will get 0 entropy when probability of one of the classes equals 1, thus the minimum is obtained, where there is 100% chance of correct classification if you create a leaf here.

> Also, must the "question" at each node be a yes/no question and thus splits the current label space into 2?

No, you could easily create decision trees with arbitrary number of children. Simply splitting into two is much simplier from computational point of view (it is easier to quantify whether there is a splitting point which is good than whether there are multiple ones which together create nice splitting). In particular this is also the reason why you can efficiently learn linaer classifiers (like logistic regression, perceptron, svm) and not multithreshold linear classifiers (like multithreshold entropy linear classifier) - it is way more complex to built multithreshold models, but still - possible and for some cases favorable.

Comment: I'm still confused about the first part. You said "if entropy is high... thus splitting in this feature is valuable" but isn't choosing a particular partition based on choosing one that **minimizes** partition entropy (the second formula)?? At least that's what I learned from my book.

Comment: Well no. You select always the node with **highest** value, see for example https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs2750-Spring04/lectures/class21.pdf. The goal is to have the tree with **smallest** entropy, thus (as this is usually a greedy learning) you find the node which has **highest** and you split it to reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

**Decision Tree algorithm**

This algorithm works for both classifier and Regressor.

For classifier demonstration

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


df=pd.read_csv("D:\\heart.csv")

iris={"data":np.array(df[["age","sex","cp","trestbps","chol","fbs","restecg","thalach","exang","oldpeak","slope","ca","thal"]],ndmin=2),"target":np.array(df["target"]),"target_names":np.array(["No_problem","Problem"])}

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(iris["data"],iris["target"],random_state=0
)

dt=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini",random_state=100,max_depth=10,min_samples_leaf=2)

dt.fit(X_train,Y_train)

x_new=np.array([[71,0,0,112,149,0,1,125,0,1.6,1,0,2]])

prediction=dt.predict(x_new)

print("The value is : {}\n".format(prediction))

print("The name is : {}\n".format(iris["target_names"][prediction]))

print("Accurecy is : {:.2f}".format(dt.score(X_train,Y_train)*100))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer try to explain it a little bit.